# BigQuery: Using threshold with COUNT DISTINCT in WINDOW function returns error

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions

With COUNT DISTINCT, I often make use of a threshold to make it more precise. E.g. `COUNT(DISTINCT users, 100000)`.

If I am using a WINDOW function though I get an error when trying to use a threshold `COUNT_DISTINCT must have at most 1 argument(s), found 2`. E.g. here's a made-up query that demonstrates the problem:

```
SELECT
day,
COUNT(DISTINCT state, 100000) OVER (PARTITION BY year, month, day)
FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
LIMIT 1000
```

Is this by design? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT(DISTINCT) is documented as approximation when used as aggregation function, but when it is used as analytic function - it is actually the exact implementation, so you don't need extra parameter - you will get the exact result without it.